# Retain selected row after refresh in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can highlight the selected background using this example :
http://plnkr.co/edit/SkaYSbtKFdx1I9N0xP5E
but is there a way I can retain the highlighted value after page fresh. 
I am  using the localstorage module for angular (https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage) and can store the value of selected row id but how can I use it to highlight again after refresh.
I do NOT want to use Jquery.

Comment: You might want to store the last action that was made and maybe simulate the click so the highlight will occur from the action..

Comment: Arik, Interesting idea. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use local storage.

and a `ng-init`

```
$scope.setSelected = function(idSelectedVote) {
   localStorage.idSelectedVote = $scope.idSelectedVote 
   = idSelectedVote ||
     localStorage.idSelectedVote ||
     null;
   console.log(idSelectedVote);
}
```

and

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" 
    ng-init="setSelected()" 
    ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)"     
    ng-class="{selected : vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
...
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0EHarAtfMoqyIz92SMEU)

Comment: Thanks Caleb for the answer but somehow I am not able to retain the value even though your example is fine. I am not sure if using ajax to update the values is causing not to highlight it. I am looking for any obvious flaws on my side.

Comment: I think the problem is because localstorage works only with string so it may not work if the id is returned as number. In my case, I had to convert my id field to string and now it works fine.

Comment: That'll do it! Glad you figured it out